# how to configure or setup spock_sharedField__browser in Geb?

Tags: spock, geb

Can anyone please tell me where exactly spock_sharedField__browser field should be declared or initialized in Geb testing framework?

Comment: Where did you see this field? The name suggests to me like it's in some kind of Spock internals...

Comment: yes this is spock internals. When I am setting up spock + geb test case.. This was coming when test case is run through Java.

Comment: What do you mean by running a Spock test through java? You should run Spock tests using the JUnit runner that is provided by Spock.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/what's the problem you're having? I feel like this is the wrong way yo go about it.

Comment: @erdi : I am doing it through GroovyClassLoader and calling individual methods so that I don't want to write testNG type XML for testSuits to run. I want avoid this XML thing. Thank you.

Comment: @jk47 Yes you might be true about this. that I might be going in wrong direction. I am not getting good start examples of Geb + Spock to run testSuits and I don't want testNG type XML things to configure. Also choosing Geb + Spock main reason is that I wanted avoid boilerplate code which I have to write using Selenium. It would be good if you guys point me to better documentations for test suits. Thank you.

Comment: Spock has its own test runner so you don't need and even shouldn't use TestNG with it. If you want support for suites with Spock then you can for example use JUnit's `@Category` annotations together with gradle (http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_grouping). There is an example Geb project bult with gradle at https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle

Comment: Thank you @erdi . Also is it possible that using Spock, we can run it as standalone project so that QA guys can also add test cases along with developers?

Comment: I am eager to start contributing to Geb as I loved your project and what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "run it as standalone project" wrt using Spock.

Comment: Ok I got the link where I wanted to have both developer and QA should work on writing test cases. here is the link http://www.slideshare.net/alvarosanchezmariscal/devqa-ggx2013